# How to call a method from an object using state

Tags: reactjs

I want to call a method on button click. I have an object like this -

```
const job = {
  position: 'cashier',
  type: 'hourly',
  isAvailable: true,
  showDetails() {
      const accepting = this.isAvailable ? 'is accepting applications' : "is not currently accepting applications";

      console.log(`The ${this.position} position is ${this.type} and ${accepting}.`);
  }
};
```

I am assigning job object to state

```
this.state = {
  job : null
}

this.setState({
  job : job
})
```

On click of a button I have to call showDetails method

```
<button className="showDetails" onClick={this.showDetails}></button>

showDetails(){
  this.state.job.showDetails()
}
```

but this is not working. What I am doing wrong here. how can I call showDetails method ?

Comment: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
const job = {
  position: 'cashier',
  type: 'hourly',
  isAvailable: true,
  showDetails: () => {
      const accepting = this.isAvailable ? 'is accepting applications' : "is not currently accepting applications";

      console.log(`The ${this.position} position is ${this.type} and ${accepting}.`);
  },
};
```

Change your button to this

```
<button className="showDetails" onClick={() => this.showDetails()}></button>
```

Comment: I got some idea based on your comment. It's working now. One thing I would like to know - what is difference between onClick={() => this.showDetails()} and onClick = this.showDetails

Comment: The difference is you do not have to bind your functions when you use () => {}

Answer (score -1):

It's probably because you are not binding `this` to your function. Please [read this documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) and bind `this` to `showDetails`.

If you just use `onClick={this.state.job.showDetails}`, it should work.

Comment: This will not work since by passing `this.state.job.showDetails` directly, `showDetails` will lose the calling context of `this.state.job`